# How can I use socket io for just server client communication?

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io

I would like to build a web page with interactive content.

I would like to use socket IO, but I've got a problem when I send two number from client to the server.

The server adds the two numbers and sends for every user (but I want just send back to the one user). I  wouldn't like to store the users. So I would like to ask how can I build this example using NodeJS and Socket IO?

Comment: but the broadcast method is not good for me because send the message everyone else except me.but I want to send just a server and want to send the data for me back I don't want to send the data everyone.

Answer (score 1):

if you look into socket.io [docs](https://socket.io/docs/), you will find out that you can specify the `key` for each message you send, for instance:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // specify a clientId for each client you have, you may define it at the moment the connection starts.
  socket.emit(`news:${clientId}`, { hello: 'world' });
});
```

And, on the client side, you have:

```
socket.on(`news:${myClientId}`, function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

You may generate this `id` randomly by using many libraries, for instance [Node-Forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge).

Hope it helps! Feel free to ask further.